# How to fix PrintWriter not initializing in If statement

Tags: java, file, printwriter

I am trying to prompt the user whether or not they would like to export data to a file. If they pick y, then it should then prompt for which file they would like it to be exported to. It prints the statement, but never asks and therefore never works.

I am new to Java, this is an online course so I have tried everything to my current knowledge. I have tried concatenating, initializing before the loops, etc.

`System.out.println("Would you like to export the passwords to a file? (y or n)");
        String userFileC = in.next();`

```
    while(!(userFileC.equals("y")) && !(userFileC.equals("n")))
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to export the passwords to a file? (y or n)");
        userFileC = in.next();
    }
    if(userFileC.equals("y"))
    {
        System.out.println("What is the name of the file? (Remember .txt)");
        String chosenFile = in.next();
        PrintWriter outfile = new PrintWriter(new File(chosenFile));
    }
```

I would like it to the export data to stated file.

Comment: Is this code producing an error? If so please edit your question with the stacktrace or error.  If it does not compile please let us know what the compile error is.

Answer (score -1):

You must use Scanner class to take the input.

```
Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
```

Then you take the input as

```
String userFileC = sc.next();
```

Hope this might help you.